# How to find the lowest sustained value

Tags: sql-server

Is there a non brute force/efficient way to determine the minimum value sustained for x minutes from a sql table with a structure like below? This table will have 1 record per case_id, per channel_index, per second and there can be 20 channels per case and thousands of cases in this table. I will need to perform this query per case and per channel. I need to find the lowest, and highest, value that occurred for 3 consecutive minutes.

value_duration is already calculated to make these types of queries a little faster. It is in seconds and can be completely random. This indicates the time between consecutive readings received from a channel.

```
case_id     channel_index start_time              dms_value              value_duration
----------- ------------- ----------------------- ---------------------- --------------
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:39.000 69.5769729614258       2
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:41.000 69.7469329833984       2
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:43.000 69.8547210693359       1
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:44.000 69.8475494384766       1
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:45.000 69.9703216552734       2
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:47.000 69.9699172973633       1
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:48.000 70.0099258422852       2
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:50.000 70.2449035644531       1
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:51.000 70.0424575805664       2
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:53.000 70.1216125488281       1
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:54.000 69.5616912841797       1
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:55.000 69.5902786254883       2
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:57.000 70.0330581665039       1
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:58.000 70.4709854125977       1
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:24:59.000 70.7001647949219       2
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:25:01.000 70.274040222168        1
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:25:02.000 69.7524795532227       1
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:25:03.000 69.4606552124023       2
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:25:05.000 69.6096954345703       1
2668        0             2011-09-28 10:25:06.000 69.8238906860352       1
```

I am hoping not to have to run through a loop testing for a value, incrementing, and then testing the next, and so on.

For example, from the above data set if I wanted to know the lowest value for 5 consecutive seconds it would be 69.8238906860352. If I needed it for 8 consecutive seconds it would be 69.9703216552734.

Here is the full table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[continuous_data](
    [case_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [channel_index] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [start_time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [dms_type] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [dms_value] [float] NOT NULL,
    [value_duration] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [error_code] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

EDIT 3-5-12:
SO I implemented a brute force way to calculate the lowest sustained values and it seems to work ok when a specific case has a few thousand records but when tested on a case that had 1.1 million I ended up cancelling it after 37 minutes... Here is the code I am using. Anyone have ideas on optimization?

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetSustainedValues]( 
  @case_id int,
  @time_limit int, 
  @bypass_only bit = NULL)
as 
begin

DECLARE @time DateTime, @channelindex int, @lastchannelindex int
DECLARE @tmin float, @tmax float, @min float, @max float, @caseid int

DECLARE @results TABLE(case_id int, channel_index int, max float null, min float null)
DECLARE CursorName CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT start_time, channel_index from continuous_data where case_id = @case_id order by channel_index, start_time
OPEN CursorName
FETCH NEXT FROM CursorName INTO @time, @channelindex
SET @lastchannelindex = @channelindex
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --PRINT 'hello' --'Chennel:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @channelindex,128) + '  Time:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @time,128)
    IF @lastchannelindex != @channelindex
    BEGIN
        --PRINT 'Starting new channel:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @channelindex,128)
        -- we are starting on a new channel so insert that data into the results
        -- table and reset the min/max
        INSERT INTO @results(case_id, channel_index, max, min) VALUES(@case_id, @lastchannelindex, @max, @min)
        SET @max = null
        SET @min = null
        SET @lastchannelindex = @channelindex
    END

    Select @tmax = MAX(dms_value), @tmin = MIN(dms_value)
    from continuous_data
    where case_id = @case_id and channel_index = @channelindex and start_time between DATEADD(s, -(@time_limit-1), @time) and @time 
    HAVING SUM(value_duration) >= @time_limit
    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        IF @max IS null OR @tmin > @max
        BEGIN
            --PRINT 'Setting max:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @tmin,128) + ' for channel:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @channelindex,128)
            set @max = @tmin
        END

        IF @min IS null OR @tmax < @min
        BEGIN
            set @min = @tmax
        END
    END
    --PRINT 'Max:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @max,128) + '  Min:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @min,128)
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorName INTO @time, @channelindex
END
CLOSE CursorName
DEALLOCATE CursorName
--PRINT 'Max:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @max,128) + '  Min:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @min,128)
SELECT * FROM @results
end
```

EDIT: 3-7-2012
Still have not found an answer. Is there a more efficient way to do this using a .Net dll that could be called from a stored proc? Looking for any suggestions here. Thanks!

Comment: Is value duration in minutes, and is it always 1 or 2?

Comment: No. The value_duration can be anything. The sample data set I selected just has 1 or 2. It is just the difference in time between samples in seconds.

Comment: When you say lowest sustained value, do you mean that the dms_value has to be equal or lower during the entire timespan?

Comment: Exactly! Has to be equal or lower during the duration specified which is currently 3 minutes.

Comment: This is hard in non-procedural SQL. What you're going to have to do is a self-join that aggregates all the overlapping 3-minute groupings by MAX(dms_value), put that into a subquery, and then take MIN(dms_value) from that subquery. If you show your table structure, I can help with the actual SQL.

Comment: @JohnPick See my answer. Group by alone won't work, but it can be done nicely with window queries.

Comment: @Martin SQL Server, not Oracle.

Comment: Anyone have a solution using procedural SQL then? It looks like SQL Server 2012 might have window queries now but I can't guarantee my customers will have that installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but do you mean something like this?

```
select min(value_duration) as lowest, max(value_duration) as highest from mytable where case_id=2668 and start_time between Cast('2011-09-28 10:26:04' as datetime) and cast('2011-09-28 10:26:07' as datetime);
```

This query retrieves the lowest and highest value_duration for case 2668, between 10:26:04 and 10:26:07.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That query just returns the single highest/lowest value over a time period. What I need is what is the highest/lowest sustained value for 3 minutes.

Comment: How often do you need to check for lowest/highest during these 3 minutes? Once a second? 10 seconds? Minute?

Comment: The plan is that when a completed case is imported the lowest/highest value will be calculated for each channel and stored with the case. So it will only happen once per case.

Answer (score 0):

select top 3 value_duration from mytable where case_id=2668 and start_time between Cast('2011-09-28 10:26:04' as datetime) and cast('2011-09-28 10:26:07' as datetime) order by value_duration
union
select top 3 value_duration from mytable where case_id=2668 and start_time between Cast('2011-09-28 10:26:04' as datetime) and cast('2011-09-28 10:26:07' as datetime) order by value_duration
union DESC;

Answer (score 0):

*You may have to debug this because I don't have access to a DB Server here.*

Conceptually, it should work like this (on *Oracle*):

```
select case_id, channel_index,
     min(su_min) as sustained_min,
     max(su_max) as sustained_max
from (
    select case_id, channel_index, start_time,
        min(dms_value) over (partition by case_id, channel_index order by start_time 
             range numtodsinterval(3, 'minute') preceeding) as su_max,
        max(dms_value) over (partition by case_id, channel_index order by start_time 
             range numtodsinterval(3, 'minute') preceeding) as su_min, 
        min(start_time) over (partition by case_id, channel_index order by start_time)
             as first_time
    from  data_table order by start_time 
    ) as su_data
where  
    first_time + numtodsinterval(3, 'minute') <= start_time
group by
    case_id, channel_index
```

This should get you the min/max value that was not exceeded/underrun during three consecutive minutes (there may be some details to consider with values just outside of the interval).

Essentially, you first compute the min/max values for all time intervals, then you pick the highest/lowest of those. The `first_time` clause is used to exclude values at the start of the time series.

EDIT: The solution is actually for Oracle, but the important bits are standard SQL:2003.

Comment: I'll test this out. Also, this is on SQL Server 2008, not Oracle so I'll see if there is an equivalent statement.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I got two questions mixed up. The statement should be pure SQL:2003 (except for the numtointerval bit), so there is a good chance the sqlserver supports it.

Comment: Actually I am having a problem with the range function. There does not seem to be an equivalent in SQL Server. What exactly does that do?

Comment: It limits the selected window from 3 minutes before the start_time of the current row to the current row. This does not seem to be supported by SQL Server, not even in the latest version https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254392/over-clause-enhancement-request-rows-and-range-window-sub-clauses

Answer (score 0):

This is tested against your data and matches your results.

I'm doing a self join on the [Case] table and filtering for rows where c1.start_time < c2.start_time.

Then selecting rows where end_time-start_time=desired time diff.

Then using a sub-query to get the max(dms_value) in that range.

Then grouping by case_id, channel_index and finding min (max(dms_value)).

```
declare @timeDiff int = 5  -- seconds

select case_id, channel_index, MIN(dms_max)
from 
(
    select t2.*, 
        (select MAX(dms_value) 
            from [Case] c 
            where
                c.case_id = t2.case_id and 
                c.channel_index = t2.channel_index and
                c.start_time between t2.start_time and t2.end_time) dms_max
    from
    (
        select * from (
            select c1.case_id, c1.channel_index, c1.start_time, c2.start_time end_time from [Case] c1
            inner join [Case] c2 on 
                c1.case_id = c2.case_id and 
                c1.channel_index = c2.channel_index and
                c1.start_time < c2.start_time
        )
        t
        where DATEDIFF(ss, start_time, end_time) 
            between @timeDiff - 1 and @timeDiff - 1 + 
            (select max(value_duration) from [Case] c where c.case_id = case_id and c.channel_index = channel_index)
    )
    t2
)
t3
group by case_id, channel_index
```